I'm able to load secrets from vault using Spring Cloud Config Server. I wanted to have the config client print the loaded vault secrets. Possible?
I have configured a git repo with just the properties that is needed to connect to the vault. I have a spring cloud config server project that is successfully able to connect to the vault using the externalized git repo properties and print secrets. Now I wanted my client app to print the loaded properties on the Spring Cloud Config Server app. Is it possible?
On the spring cloud config server app, this prints perfectly on the console.
@Value("${spring.datasource.password: unabletoGetVaultPassword}")
public String passwordFromVault;

But the same doesn't print on the client side. What am I missing?
Regarding pom dependencies, I have used correct ones.
On server side,
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

On the client side,
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
    </dependency>

If I could achieve this, I can make the best use of Spring Cloud Config Server to be a one stop solution to interact with vault and remove the vault interaction on all client apps. Any leads?
